# totals = FALSE still outputs totals in R package summarytools ctable()?

Tags: r, summarytools

Anyone using the R package summarytools run into this? I've set the global summarytools options to suppress totals in ctables:

```
st_options(ctable.totals=FALSE)
```

And I've also called the same in the function invocation:

```
with(df, ctable(
    gender,
    var2,
    chisq = F,
    headings = T,
    totals = FALSE
  )
```

And yet it still spits out totals in actual cross_table table data. Has anyone found a way to suppress this?

Comment: I tested this code `with(mtcars, ctable(
    vs,
    am,
    chisq = F,
    headings = T,
    totals = F
  )
)` and totals are not shown.

Comment: Totals are not shown in the rendered output - do you see them in the cross table itself?

Comment: This is my output: https://pastebin.com/7QyNSGJR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in an later version of summarytools.

```
with(tobacco, ctable(
  gender,
  smoker,
  chisq = F,
  headings = T,
  totals = FALSE
))

## Cross-Tabulation, Row Proportions  
## gender * smoker  
## Data Frame: tobacco  
## 
## -------- -------- ------------- -------------
##            smoker           Yes            No
##   gender                                     
##        F            147 (30.1%)   342 (69.9%)
##        M            143 (29.2%)   346 (70.8%)
##     <NA>              8 (36.4%)    14 (63.6%)
## -------- -------- ------------- -------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a message from the devs on Github that this is actually an intended feature and if we want to drop it from the crosstab, we have to do it manually. Thanks Marco!